# Show Dialog nearly full screen in my case (With ActionBar & overlay)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am working with [Android Support package](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

I have created a dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Since I would like the dialog show in a full screen, so I applied the theme `Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` to it & it works.

I have following two questions:

1. I would like my dialog to show like full screen still but leave the top **ActionBar** not be covered by it, what Theme should I use then?
2. How to have an gray color overlay to also show the view covered by the dialog (assume my 1st qustion has resolved)?

Comment: Found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment

Answer (score 2):

1. The only working solution I found is to implement pseudo-dialog based on fragment.
2. This approach might cause some difficulties to do shadow. At least, I didn't do that.

Code sample how to do (1):

```
public class MyDialog extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... your code
}

public void show(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    String tag = MyDialog.class.getName();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, this, tag);
    ft.commit();
}

private void dismiss() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(this);
    ft.commit();
}
}
```